# how to get value of textbox in webdatagrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

i always get a null value in a textbox from grid.here is my code on my click event:

```
            foreach (GridRecord row in wdgTroubleshootCreateEdit.Rows)
            {
                int workflowCATParameterId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Items[0].Value);
                TextBox workflowCATParameterValue =
                    (TextBox)row.Items[value].FindControl("txtWorkflowCATParameterValue");
```

`workflowCATParameterValue.text` always null

Comment: I would suspect the value of `value` first. Is this set to the right column name or index?

Comment: yes.i get the right index.  int value = wdgTroubleshootCreateEdit.Columns.FromKey("WorkflowCATParameterValue").Index;

Comment: i also check the viewstate of textbox is true.

Answer (score 2):

I am with latest service release of 11.2. I tried:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   TextBox text = WebDataGrid1.Rows[0].Items[0].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
   var rrr = text.Text;
}
```

and it works fine :)  where my grid is called WebDataGrid1 and first column is templated containing TextBox named Text:

```
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid1" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="400px">
    <Columns>
        <ig:TemplateDataField Key="TemplateField_0">
            <header text="TemplateField_0" />

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

```
        </ig:TemplateDataField>
    </Columns>
    <Behaviors>
        <ig:EditingCore>
            <behaviors>
                <ig:CellEditing>
                </ig:CellEditing>
            </behaviors>
        </ig:EditingCore>
        <ig:Activation>
        </ig:Activation>
    </Behaviors>
    <Templates>
        <ig:ItemTemplate ID="WebDataGrid1Template1" runat="server" 
            TemplateID="Template1">
        </ig:ItemTemplate>
    </Templates>
</ig:WebDataGrid>
```

I tested it with IE 9 :)

Answer (score 0):

By javascript you can do this:

```
function OnExitedEditMode(sender,e){
    var row = e.getCell().get_row();
    var text = row.get_cellByColumnKey("YourDataKey").get_value();
    ....
}
```

And in your WebDataGrid you need to put this:

```
<Behaviors>
    <ig:EditingCore>
        <Behaviors>
            <ig:CellEditing EditModeActions-MouseClick="Single">
                <ColumnSettings>
                    ...
                </ColumnSettings>
                <CellEditingClientEvents ExitedEditMode="OnExitedEditMode" />
            </ig:CellEditing>
        </Behaviors>
    </ig:EditingCore>
</Behaviors>
```